# Execute a function calling a promise first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs application I have the following code :

```
handleRoutingErrors();
if ($rootRouter._currentInstruction !== null) {
    currentRouteData = makeRouteData($rootRouter._currentInstruction);
    breadcrumb.push(currentRouteData);
}
```

The `handleRoutingErrors` function contains an xhr call, so, the code bellow this function will be executed first, I want when only `handleRoutingErrors` finishes the XHR call to execute the following code.

There is a solution if I moved the other code inside the `handleRoutingErrors` function, and only execute it when I call the promise's `then` function, but I don't want to move it inside the function.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

The `handleRoutingErrors` doesn't always call the promise :

```
function handleRoutingErrors() {
    ...
    if (...) {
        process().then(function(data) {
        ...
        });
    }else{
        //None async code
    }
}
```

Comment: `handleRoutingErrors()` returns something? You can use callback.

Comment: return the subsequent promise from `handleRoutingErrors()`

Comment: @MJr it doesn't return anything, please check my edit.

Comment: @DanielA.White can't do that because the function doesn't always call the promise, please check my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You should change `handleRoutingErrors()` to always return a promise.  If it doesn't do anything async, just add `return Promise.resolve()` to return a resolved promise.

You can then always add `.then()` when you call it.